# Communication Manager Business Edition 6000 - understanding bundle equipment

Tags: cisco

I have a Cisco Communication Manager Business Edition 6000 specifications. Can you explain some facts about it.

[Link to specification](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByHsfq2aAojlMTBIWGpyQzFJdUk/edit?usp=sharing)

According to this, we have **BE6K-ST-BDL-K9 (#1)** and it contans:
1.UPM - Unified Provision Manager (for control and management)
2. VCS - Video Control Server (with 5 traversal calls and 10 non-traversal)

Also bundle has #3 CCX (Contact center express) Promo bundle.

Everything seems to be OK, but then we can find **R-CBE6K-K9 (#35)** and **BE6K-9X-PAK (#36)**.
BE6K-9X-PAK contains:
1. UCM - Unified communication manager (for calls)
2. Unity Connection (Voice mail)
3. CUP - CISCO unified Presence (presence visibility and instand messaging).

As I know we can use up to 5 application on BE 6000, but we have six: Provision manager, UCM, Unity, CUP, VCS and CCX. **Where is mistake and what application we will have?**

Other questions are about user licenses. 
1. We have 50 Enhanced user licenses. If I am right it meens 50 account entries (numbers), but not 50 end devices? 
2.Enhanced user license allow to work simultaneously only one device, it meens that I can connect with Jabber via my PC, and after work disconnect and connect from home from my iPad?

3. What is JABBER-IM-ADDON #51?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

CCX comes as complimentary like it does with CUCM purchases. You will have rest of the utilities installed but CCX would likely come in a DVD which you can install on one of your own machines.